# Is a very harsh downshift indiciative of transmission failure?

Tags: transmission, automatic-transmission, hyundai, accent

I have a 2015 Hyundai Accent with a 6-speed auto transmission.

The transmission shift smooth almost all the time.

But at certain speeds , if I completely completely depress the throttle from like 0%-100% rapdily (essentially stomp it), the car downshifts very hard with a thud that reverberates throughout the body of the car.

For example, if I drive along at 40km with the rpm at like 1500, in 4th gear, and throttle just barely pressed to maintain speed, and then immediately mash the throttle, there is a very abrupt thud / impact in the tranmission before the downshift. I have never experienced this is a auto transmission before.

What could be causing this, and it this a sign of transmission failure?

Comment: Not a full answer, but considering your further comments below, it may be prudent to have your motor mounts checked for wear and excess slop, and check that the CV joints are not showing any rotational free play at all between the trans output stubs and the wheel stubs.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not indicative of transmission failure ... for now. Doing what you're doing to a car which isn't made for it is a good way for transmission failure. When you stomp on the gas like you are doing, engine RPMs go up sharply, the transmission creates higher line pressures, and the transmission downshifts quickly (what used to be known as "passing gear"). All of this together gives a sudden jolt to the entire vehicle through the drivetrain. The transmission can handle this every so often (such as emergency situations), but it's not designed to do this over and over again. By stomping on the gas pedal you are creating undue wear on all the drivetrain components, not just the transmission.

Comment: These are just the repro steps I have given, there are times it happens when I just want to go 80% throttle and it downshift.

Comment: Anytime you get on the throttle as you are suggesting, you are going to get a sharp downshift.

Comment: @Scorb I don't want to put words in Paulster2's mouth, but I think what he's saying is that it's not the transmission at fault, it's the nut behind the wheel! ;-)

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Not trying to be contradictory here, but I have driven many vehicles over my 20 years of driving, and I know the difference between a sharp downshift, and a jerk/thud that bangs and reverberates throughout the frame of the vehicle.

Comment: @Scorb - Well, then with all due respect, maybe your description is lacking. Maybe there is something wrong with it. Maybe you should take it somewhere there is a live/warm body who can diagnose whatever you believe is wrong with it. This is the internet and we can only give you answers based on what you tell us.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I literally said "the car downshifts very hard with a thud" and you somehow conclude that the means "a normal downshift"....and my description is lacking? With all due respect....I think the problem lies with your cynical interpretation and not my clear and accurate description.

Comment: @Scorb - Again. You can take or leave my advice. I'm sorry it doesn't jibe with your preconceived notion that something is wrong with your vehicle. My apologies that what I wrote is not what you expected. And of course, no fault lies in your explanation. I wish you well and your vehicle, too.

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved this by resetting the adaptive shift memory in the tranmission control unit computer.

I used the veepeak OBD scanner, and connected to it with the iOS Car Scanner app. Then once connected, nested in the settings is an option to clear the adaptive shift memory.

I cannot believe this actually solved the issue, but it did.